# How should I be using playwright's toHaveScreenshot() within a cucumber test in a React Typescript project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cucumber, playwright

I'm wanting to implement visual regression testing into a ReactJS app. I already have playwright setup called through cucumber for some other BDD UI tests and wanted to make use of the built in toHaveScreenShot method for visual regression. However, whenever I run the test it throws this error:

> **Error: toHaveScreenshot() must be called during the test**

Here's the test script definition:

**package.json excerpt**

```
"test:e2e": "cucumber-js --require cucumber.conf.js --require features/step_definitions/**/*.js --format @cucumber/pretty-formatter",
```

Here's an example of the code:

**cucumber.conf.js**

```
const {
  Before,
  BeforeAll,
  AfterAll,
  After,
  setDefaultTimeout,
} = require("@cucumber/cucumber");
const { chromium } = require("playwright");

// in milliseconds
setDefaultTimeout(60000);

// launch the browser
BeforeAll(async function () {
  global.browser = await chromium.launch({
    headless: false,
    slowMo: 1000,
  });
});

// close the browser
AfterAll(async function () {
  await global.browser.close();
});

// Create a new browser context and page per scenario
Before(async function () {
  global.context = await global.browser.newContext();
  global.page = await global.context.newPage();
});

// Cleanup after each scenario
After(async function () {
  await global.page.close();
  await global.context.close();
});
```

**homepage.feature**

```
Feature: Homepage
A simple homepage

    Scenario: Someone visiting the homepage
        Given a new visitor to the site
        When they load the homepage
        Then they see the page
```

**homepage.js**

```
const { Given, When, Then } = require("@cucumber/cucumber");
const { expect } = require("@playwright/test");

Given("a new visitor to the site", function () {});

When("they load the homepage", async () => {
  await page.goto("http://localhost:3000/");
});

Then("they see the page", async () => {
  const locator = page.locator('img[alt="An image you expect to see"]');
  await expect(locator).toBeVisible();
  await expect(locator).toHaveScreenshot();
});
```

I think the error is complaining that I'm not writing my tests in the usual test() method, but I've not come across anything similar in searches and don't know how to give this context, assuming that is the problem, while using Cucumber.

Can anyone suggest a solution? I'm at a bit of a loss.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `await expect(locator).toHaveScreenshot();` ?

Comment: You're right! However, updating and running still gives the same problem. I've edited the post to match.

Comment: Also added in a more complete example with the node script, cucumber config, and gherkin bdd test. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this issue but could not find a way to fix it. I will update here if I see a solution.

Comment: we are not alone. https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/15275 :)